# desquitar vs desquitarse

Tags: vocabulario, reflexivos

Is there a difference between desquitar and desquitarse?

[SpanishDict](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/desquitar) gives a distinction between desquitar and desquitarse, with the former seeming more positive/neutral and the later with a negative connotation:

desquitar: to make up for doing something bad, to deduct

desquitarse: to get even, to get back at someone for something, to take something out on someone, and to obtain satisfaction.

However, [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/desquitar?m=form) gives three definitions for desquitar but there is no mention of its use as a pronominal verb:

1. tr. Particularmente en el juego, reintegrarse de lo perdido, restaurar una pérdida. U. t. c. prnl. (to make up for something lost, especially in gambling)
2. tr. descontar. (to deduct)
3. tr. Tomar satisfacción, vengar una ofensa, daño o derrota. U. t. c. prnl. (Take satisfaction, avenge an offense, harm or defeat.)

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/desquitarse) gives the same definitions for both desquitar and desquitarse.

[WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=desquitar) seems to only mention desquitarse.

Any help in understanding when to use a reflexive here would be much appreciated.

Comment: But it's mentioned in 1. and 3. (I've copied that part from the DLE): U.t.c.prnl - Usado también como pronominal.

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember having ever seen this verb used as non pronominal.

Comment: I agree. Instead of "U. t. c. prnl." (usado también como pronominal) DLE should say "usado casi siempre como pronominal".
Googling "desquitar" (exact search, with quotes), it's really hard to find non-pronominal usages. I could only find "¿Cómo puedo desquitar mi sueldo?" and "INE planea desquitar la quincena con monitoreo a programas de opinión y espectáculos". And I have to confess I don't understand what those mean.